# Datetime format is miss matching in c# when hosting

Tags: c#, datetime

I had a situation that locally working but not in hosting (godaddy.com)

`DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(TextBoxSelectedDate.Text.Trim());`

`string d = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");`//localhost out put 2013-10-13

```
 DateTime.Parse(d);
```

but when I host is giving this exception

`System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.`

Why is this

Thanks

Comment: What input string is being provided in the textbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hoster might be using a different language / region setting than you. Try calling [`Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kc8s65zs.aspx) with a specific culture object:

```
DateTime.Parse("2013-10-13", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("the name of your culture, en-US for example"))
```

You can find a list of culture names here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb896001.aspx

You can also use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`

Answer (score 1):

You use a *format string* when you go from `DateTime` to `string`. Use the same format string when you go in the opposite direction:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(d, "yyyy-MM-dd", null)
```

If you want to be absolutely sure the current culture of your thread doesn't mess things up, you can use the invariant culture:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(d, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```